# Slow SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS Query

Tags: wp-query, database, mysql, performance, pre-get-posts

We are experiencing very slow performance with queries that use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` within the admin section of WordPress.

We currently have about 125,000 posts on our site and use Varnish to cache the front-end and are on WordPress version 4.2.3.

The problem arises when there are people using the admin section of WordPress and WordPress will run a query like the one below:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%denali%') 
OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%denali%'))) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%denali%' DESC, 
wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Is there a patch to fix this issue or some sort of `pre_get_posts` filter I can run?

I plan on removing some post revisions and doing some DB optimization, but first wanted to see if there was some sort of fix for this within WordPress.

I have come across similar issues while searching for this, but most of those issues seem to be 2-6 years old.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The use of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is not really a problem, although it incurs an overhead.

What happens is, WordPress uses `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in order to determine the total posts that would have been returned, if no `LIMIT` clause was provided. This is necessary in order to calculate and provide you with correct pagination links.

Disabling it unconditionally is guaranteed to break things all over the place.

If you can identify specific queries that suffer from its use, and you can do without pagination, then you could hook to `pre_get_posts` and conditionally set the `no_found_rows` parameter to true.
This, however, is more a hack than a solution.

The proper solution is to use a database query caching mechanism, either on the side of the database, or on the WordPress side using a plugin such as [Advanced Post Cache](https://github.com/Automattic/advanced-post-cache) (developed for and used in WordPress.com)

Answer (score -1):

$query->set('no_found_rows', true);

Comment: Please explain, *why* this should help the OP. Just a short code snippet is not an answer. Thanks.